# Tumblr JS/Jquery Infinite Scroll / Masonry Glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I'm new to JS/JQuery and masonry so this is probably some dumb mistake, but i've searched a lot for answers and i'm completely out of ideas.

The issue is overlapping posts/divs.
[image]
http://folkherofilms.tumblr.com/tagged/thrilljockey/chrono

Here's the full theme code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>{Title}</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
        <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
        {block:Description}
            <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
        {/block:Description}

<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/cbgnuxd/KqQmy0t7l/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/cbgnuxd/LE0my0t7x/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/cbgnuxd/PW6my0t86/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/cbgnuxd/He2myzqh0/lazyyt.js"></script>

<!-- SHARERS -->
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher:'3a7d8263-9ce0-4500-9413-f40167dad735'});</script>

<!-- OTHER CRAP SCRIPT -->

<script>

$(function(){

// YT LAZY LOAD
$('.js-lazyYT').lazyYT();

// INDEX PAGE
if (document.location.href == "http://folkherofilms.tumblr.com/") {
    window.location.href = "http://folkherofilms.tumblr.com/index";
}

if (document.location.href == "http://folkherofilms.tumblr.com/index") {
    $('body').addClass('static');
    $('.item').addClass('autoheight');
}

// CASE STUDY PAGES
if ( document.location.href.indexOf('tagged/') > -1 ) {
    $('#sidebar').fadeIn('slow');
}

// ABOUT PAGE

if (document.location.href == "http://folkherofilms.tumblr.com/about") {
    $('body').addClass('static');
    $('.item img').css('width','auto');
    $('.item').addClass('autoheight');
}

// TEMPORARY PORTFOLIO PAGE

if (document.location.href == "http://folkherofilms.tumblr.com/portfolio") {
    $('body').addClass('static');
    $('.item').addClass('autoheight');
}

// PORTFOLIO PAGE
if (document.location.href == "http://folkherofilms.tumblr.com/tagged/portfolio") {
    $('#sidebar, .sharers').css('display','none');
    $('#maincontainer, #headercontainer').css('width','1040px');
    $('#maincontainer').css('top','190px');
    $('#container').css('margin-left','0px');
    $('.item').removeClass('m l autoheight');
    $('.item').addClass('s');
}

// FIELD NOTES POSTS
if ($('.item.fieldnotes').length ) {
    $('body').addClass('static');  
    $('#disqus_things, .sharers').show();
    $('.item').addClass('autoheight');   

}

// FIELD NOTES PAGE
if (document.location.href == "http://folkherofilms.tumblr.com/tagged/fieldnotes") {
    $('body').addClass('static');
    $('.item').removeClass('m s');
    $('.item img').css('width','auto');
    $('#disqus_things, .sharers').hide();
}

// CONTACT PAGE
if (document.location.href == "http://folkherofilms.tumblr.com/contact") {
    $('body').addClass('static');
}

// DEFAULT SIZE POSTS
$('.item:not(.m, .l)').addClass('s');

// 404 PAGE
if ($('p:contains("The URL you requested could not be found.")').length > 0) { 
    $('.item, .sharers').hide();
    $('#notfound').show();
}

});
</script>

<!-- META -->

<meta name="image:Background" content=""/>
<meta name="image:Logo" content=""/>
<meta name="image:Header Background" content=""/>
<meta name="color:Text Color" content="#666"/>
<meta name="color:Link Underline" content="#5c7ea5"/>
<meta name="text:Disqus Shortname" content="" />

<!-- CSS -->

<style>

html, body {height:100%}

#tumblr_controls, #tumblr_controls iframe {display:none!important}

body {
margin:0;
background-color:#ccc;
background-image:url('{image:Background}');
font-family:Pt Sans, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: {Color:Text Color};
overflow-x:hidden;
}

.hide {display:none!important}

#sitecredit {
position:fixed;
bottom:6px;
right:10px;
}

#sitecredit img {width:21px;opacity:0.5}
#sitecredit img:hover {opacity:0.9}

h3 {font-size:10px}

#disqus_things {display:none}
#disqus_things .post {width:100%}

#maincontainer {
visibility:hidden;
position: relative;
top: 200px;
width: 1135px;
height:100%; /*FOR SAFARI */
margin: 0 auto;
padding-bottom:100px;
}

#infscr-loading {opacity:0}

/* STATIC PAGES */

.static #sidebar {display:none!important}
.static #maincontainer, .static #headercontainer, .static #container {width:910px}
.static #maincontainer {top:190px}
.static #container {margin-left:0px}
.static .item {width:850px;padding:10px 20px;position:relative!important;}
.static .sharers {display:none; margin:30px;}
.static .big {width:830px!important;height:467px!important}

/* HEADER */

    #header {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:50;$()
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:130px;
    background-image:url('{image:Header Background}');
    background-color:#222;
    padding:20px 0;
    font-size:10px;
    }

    #headercontainer {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block!important;
    width:910px;
    transition-duration:0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration:0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration:0.5s;
    }

    #header, #header a {
    color:#fff;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

    #headerlinks {
    position:relative;
    left:170x;
    }

    #header a {
    font-size:13px;
    }

    #header div, #header a {display:inline-block}

    #logo {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 20px 0 30px;
    }

/* SIDEBAR */

    #sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 10px;
    }

    #sidebar h1 {
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    display:block;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    }

    #sidebar a {
    display:block;
    color: #5c5959;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding:3px;
    width:91px;
    margin:10px 0;
    background:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    }

/* POSTS */


    .item a {
    color: {Color:Text Color};
    color: #666;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .item a:hover {color:{Color:Link Underline}}

    .read_more {text-transform:uppercase}

    #notfound {
    display:none;
    margin: 10px 0 0 129px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 500px;
    }
    .notfound-404 {
    font-size: 300px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-style: normal;
    display: block;
    line-height: 220px;
    letter-spacing: -9px;
    text-align: left;
    }

    #container {
    z-index: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 115px;
    width: 1200px;
    }

    .item {
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin:10px;
    }

    .item img {display:block;min-width:100%;height:100%;width:auto;}
    .item p img {max-width:100%;height:auto}

    .item iframe {width:100%;height:100%;}

    div.js-lazyYT img {width:auto!important;min-width:0px;height:auto;}
    .lazyYT-title {display:none}

    p {margin:5px}

    .s {
    width:240px;
    height:200px;
    }
    .s .media {height:173px}

    .m {
    width: 500px;
    height:420px;
    }
    .m .media {height:392px}

    .text {padding:10px 0}
    .s.text, .m.text {overflow-y:auto}
    .s.text {height:180px}
    .m.text {height:400px}

    .l {width:1020px}
    .l.video iframe {height: 574px}

    .l img, .autoheight, .autoheight .media, .autoheight .media img {
    height:auto!important;
    min-height:0px;
    }

    .autoheight.nocaption .media {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    }

    .autoheight.nocaption .media img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: -5px 0;
    }

    .nocaption .media {height:100%}

    .nocaption img {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    }

    /*.nocaption.s img, .nocaption.m img {min-height: 100%}*/

    .nocaption iframe {
    height: 106%;
    margin-top: -3%;
    display:block;
    }

    h1 {font-size:14px}

    .media {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

    .caption {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    padding:0 10px;
    }

    .audio .media {height:100%}

    .audio .player-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -20px!important;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    .audio_player {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    margin:-5px!important;
    }

    .audio_player iframe {position:relative}

    .player-wrapper {z-index:70}

    .audioinfo {
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: whitesmoke;
    background: black;
    }

    .audio:hover .audioinfo {opacity:1}

/* SHARES */

.sharers {
width: 88px;
border-top: 1px dashed black;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom:50px;
text-align: center;
margin:30px 0 0 120px;
}

.sharers span {
width: 20px!important;
height: 20px!important;
background-size: 20px;
margin: 2px;
}

.stButton .stLarge:hover {
opacity: 1!important;
background-position: 0!important;
cursor:pointer;
padding-right:0px;
}

/* LIKE REBLOG */

.likereblog {display:none}
.like .likereblog {display:block}

.likereblog {padding:0px 10px 5px}
.likereblog * {
display:inline-block!important;
border-bottom:none!important;
width:15px!important;
height:15px!important;
}
.likereblog a:hover {background-color:transparent}
.likereblog svg {margin-left:10px; fill:#000}

.audio .likereblog, .nocaption .likereblog {position: absolute;z-index: 9999;}
.nocaption .likereblog, .audio .likereblog {bottom:0px}

.nocaption .likereblog svg {fill:#fff}
.nocaption .likereblog iframe {-webkit-filter:invert(1)}

/* PAGES */

.item.fieldnotes p img, .item.fieldnotes p iframe {
    width:auto!important;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

</style>    

    </head>

<!-- BODY -->

<body>

<!-- MASONRY SCRIPT -->
<script>

 $(function(){

    // IF NOT FIELD NOTES PAGE  
    if (!$('.item').hasClass('fieldnotes')) {

        // UNWRAP TITLE LINKS
        $('.item .title h1').unwrap();

        // MASONRY
        var $container = $('#container');

        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
             $container.masonry({
                columnWidth: 1,
                isOriginTop: true,
                itemSelector : '.item'
             });
        });

    }

 });
</script>

<!-- SITE CREDIT -->
<div id="sitecredit"><a href="http://dinakelbermanwebdesign.com" target="blank">
<img src="http://dinakelbermanwebdesign.com/credit.png"></a>
</div>


<!-- HEADER -->
<div id="header">
    <div id="headercontainer">
    <span id="headerwrap">
    <a href="http://folkherofilms.tumblr.com/index"><img id="logo" src="{image:Logo}"></a>

    <div id="headerlinks">
    <a href="/about">Who We Are</a> &#9679;   
    <!--a href="/tagged/portfolio">Portfolio</a> &#9679;-->
    <a href="/fieldnotes">Field Notes</a> &#9679;
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a> &#9679;
    <a href="http://folkherofilms.tumblr.com/index">Home</a>
    </div>
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------->

    </span>
    </div>   
</div>


<div id="maincontainer">

<!-- SIDEBAR -->
<div id="sidebar">
<h1>MORE PROJECTS</h1>
{block:HasPages}
{block:Pages}
<a href="{URL}">{Label}</a>
{/block:Pages}
{/block:HasPages}    

</div>

<div id="notfound"><span class="notfound-404">404</span>Page not found, please try again!</div>

<div id="container">

{block:Posts}

<!-- TEXT -->

{block:Text}
<div class="item text {TagsAsClasses}">

    <div class="caption">
    {block:Title}
    <a href="{Permalink}" class="title"><h1>{Title}</h1></a>
    {/block:Title}
    {Body}

    <div class="hide">
    {block:ContentSource}{SourceURL}{/block:ContentSource}
    </div>

    </div>

<div class="likereblog">{LikeButton color="black"}{ReblogButton}</div>
</div>
{/block:Text}

<!-- PHOTO -->

{block:Photo}
<div class="item {TagsAsClasses} photo">

    <div class="media"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}"></div>

    {block:Caption}
    <div class="caption entry">
    {Caption}
    </div>
    {/block:Caption}


<div class="likereblog">{LikeButton color="black"}{ReblogButton}</div>
</div>

    <div class="hide">
    {block:ContentSource}{SourceURL}{/block:ContentSource}
    </div>
{/block:Photo}


<!-- PANORAMA -->                                                       

{block:Panorama}
    <li class="panorama">
        {LinkOpenTag}
            <img src="{PhotoURL-Panorama}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
        {LinkCloseTag}{block:Caption}
            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
        {/block:Caption}


<div class="likereblog">{LikeButton color="black"}{ReblogButton}</div>
    </li>

        <div class="hide">
    {block:ContentSource}{SourceURL}{/block:ContentSource}
    </div>
{/block:Panorama}


<!-- PHOTOSET -->

{block:Photoset}
<div class="item {TagsAsClasses}">
<div class="media-photoset">
<div class="lightbox photo-slideshow" id="photoset_{PostID}" data-layout="{PhotosetLayout}">
{block:Photos}

<div class="photo-data">
  <div class="pxu-photo">
     <a class="tumblr-box" rel="post is-item-{PostID}" href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}">
          <img alt="{PhotoAlt}" src="{PhotoURL-500}" data-highres="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" data-width="{PhotoWidth-HighRes}" data-height="{PhotoHeight-HighRes}" class="{block:Exif}exif-yes {/block:Exif}{block:Caption}caption-yes{/block:Caption}" {block:Exif}data-camera="{block:Camera}{Camera}{/block:Camera}" data-iso="{block:ISO}{ISO}{/block:ISO}" data-aperture="{block:Aperture}{Aperture}{/block:Aperture}" data-exposure="{block:Exposure}{Exposure}{/block:Exposure}" data-focal="{block:FocalLength}{FocalLength}{/block:FocalLength}"{/block:Exif} {block:Caption}data-caption="{Caption}"{/block:Caption}>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
     <span class="info">
        Info
     </span>
  </div>
</div>
{/block:Photos}
</div>
</div>
{block:Caption}
<div class="background unrounded">
<div class="entry caption">
{Caption}

</div>
</div>
{/block:Caption}
{block:IfTags}
{block:HasTags} 
<div class="background unrounded tags clearfix">
{block:Tags} 
    <a href="{TagURL}">
        <div class="tag">{Tag}</div>
    </a>
{/block:Tags}   
</div>
{/block:HasTags}
{/block:IfTags}
<div class="meta">
<div class="part">
<a href="{Permalink}" title="Permalink">
{TimeAgo}
</a>
</div>
<div class="part heart">
<a href="{Permalink}" title="Permalink">
<i class="icon-heart"></i>
<div class="text heart"><div class="note-counter">{NoteCount}</div></div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="hide">
    {block:ContentSource}{SourceURL}{/block:ContentSource}
    </div>
{/block:Photoset}


<!-- VIDEO -->

{block:Video}
<div class="item video {TagsAsClasses}">

<div class="media">{VideoEmbed-700}</div>

{block:Caption}
<div class="caption entry">
{Caption}
</div>
{/block:Caption}

<div class="likereblog">{LikeButton color="black"}{ReblogButton}</div>

</div>
    <div class="hide">
    {block:ContentSource}{SourceURL}{/block:ContentSource}
    </div>
{/block:Video}


<!-- AUDIO -->

{block:Audio}
<div class="item audio {TagsAsClasses}">

<div class="player">
    {block:AudioPlayer}
    {block:AlbumArt}
        <img src="{AlbumArtURL}" class="albumart">
        <div class="player-wrapper">{AudioPlayerBlack}</div>
    {/block:AlbumArt}
    {/block:AudioPlayer}

    {block:AudioEmbed}
    <div class="background">
        <div class="audioembed">{AudioEmbed-500}</div>
    </div>
    {/block:AudioEmbed}
</div>

{block:Artist}
<div class="audioinfo">
{Artist}<br>
{block:TrackName}{TrackName}{/block:TrackName}
</div>
{/block:Artist}



<div>
    {block:Caption}
    <div class="caption entry">{Caption}</div>
    {/block:Caption}
</div>


<div class="likereblog">{LikeButton color="black"}{ReblogButton}</div>

</div>
    <div class="hide">
    {block:ContentSource}{SourceURL}{/block:ContentSource}
    </div>
{/block:Audio}

{/block:Posts}
</div>  

<div class="sharers">
<span st_url='{Permalink}' st_title='{Title}' class='st_twitter' displayText=''></span><span st_url='{Permalink}' st_title='{Title}' class='st_facebook' displayText=''></span><span st_url='{Permalink}' st_title='{Title}' class='st_email' displayText=''></span>
</div>

<!-- DISQUS -->
<div id="disqus_things">
    {block:IfDisqusShortname}

    <div class="post type-comments m {block:HighRes}l{/block:HighRes}">
    <div class="background fully-rounded">
    <h3 class="title">
    Comments
    </h3>
    <div class="entry comments">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var disqus_url = "{Permalink}"; var disqus_title ="{block:PostTitle}{PostTitle}{/block:PostTitle}";
    </script>
    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var disqus_shortname = '{text:Disqus shortname}'; 

    function load_disqus()
    {
    (function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);                                                
    })();
    }


    load_disqus(function() {});

    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
    <a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">blog comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>

    </div>

    {/block:IfDisqusShortname}                
</div>

<!-- PAGINATION FOR INFINITE SCROLL -->
    <div class="pagination">
    {block:Pagination}
    {block:NextPage}
    <a href="{NextPage}">NEXT</a>
    {/block:NextPage}
    {/block:Pagination}
    </div>    

</div>   


<!-- IMAGE LOAD JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/cbgnuxd/l2rmz5u6v/imagesloaded.js"></script>

<!-- INFINITE SCROLL -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/cbgnuxd/saomz5tvi/jquery.infinitescroll.js"></script>

<!-- INFINITE SCROLL -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var $tumblelog = $('#container');
    $tumblelog.infinitescroll({
        navSelector: ".pagination",
        nextSelector: ".pagination a:last-child",
        itemSelector: ".item",

    loading: {
    finished: undefined,
    finishedMsg: "",
    img: "",
    msg: null,
    loadingText: "<em></em>",
    },

    },

    function (newElements) {
        var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
            opacity: 0
        });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $newElems.animate({
                opacity: 1
            });

            $('.item:not(:has(.caption))').addClass('nocaption');

            // IF NOT FIELD NOTES PAGE  
             if (!$('.item').hasClass('fieldnotes')) {
                // UNWRAP TITLE LINKS
                $('.item .title h1').unwrap();
            }

            // PORTFOLIO PAGE
            if (document.location.href == "http://folkherofilms.tumblr.com/tagged/portfolio") {
                $('#sidebar, .sharers').css('display','none');
                $('#maincontainer, #headercontainer').css('width','1040px');
                $('#maincontainer').css('top','190px');
                $('#container').css('margin-left','0px');
                $('.item').removeClass('m l autoheight');
                $('.item').addClass('s');
            }

            // FIELD NOTES POSTS
            if ($('.item.fieldnotes').length ) {
                $('body').addClass('static');  
                $('#disqus_things, .sharers').show();
                $('.item').addClass('autoheight');   

            }

            // FIELD NOTES PAGE
            if (document.location.href == "http://folkherofilms.tumblr.com/tagged/fieldnotes") {
                $('body').addClass('static');
                $('.item').removeClass('m s');
                $('.item img').css('width','auto');
                $('#disqus_things, .sharers').hide();
            }

            $tumblelog.masonry('appended', $newElems);
        });
    });
    $tumblelog.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $tumblelog.masonry({
            columnWidth: function (containerWidth) {
                return containerWidth / 100;
            }
        });
    });

})();  

// NOCAPTION POSTS
$('.item:not(:has(.caption))').addClass('nocaption');

</script>

</body>

<script>
$(function(){
    // SITE LOADING
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#maincontainer").css('visibility','visible');
});

})
</script>

</html>
```

I've tried a variety of solutions and the glitch keeps getting "fixed" but then coming back.  Could Tumblr be messing with the JS somehow?

Comment: Maybe telling us what you've tried would be helpful. I really don't think anyone is willing to go through all that code. And it isn't formatted properly, by the way.

Comment: Its hard to tell, but my first guess would be images loaded. You are calling it in three places, when in reality it should be called once for images already in the DOM, and again for images add to the DOM via infinite scroll. The later is correct, so I would double check the first. Also can you confirm at what point this happens?

Comment: sorry for the huge code, i'm new to this site, didn't want to leave out anything that might be relevant . . . thank you for your images loaded idea, i'll check that out!  not sure when it happens because it's happening so inconsistently.

Comment: This is a very common question, actually. I've seen it at least 5 times in the last year on StackOverflow. So, the answer is out there already. Basically, what needs to happen: on your callback for Infinite Scroll you need check the `.imagesLoaded()` function before attaching the posts.

Comment: thanks for the help but it turned out not to be imagesLoaded but that i forgot to insert my masonry options after the infinite scroll!  i.e. i needed the last masonry to say                  
`columnWidth: 1,
                isOriginTop: true,
                itemSelector : '.item'` in both places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem here was that i didn't include the masonry options after the infinite scroll.  i.e. my masonry at the top was this:

```
// MASONRY
        var $container = $('#container');

        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
             $container.masonry({
                columnWidth: 1,
                isOriginTop: true,
                itemSelector : '.item'
             });
        });
```

and after the infinite scroll it needed to match:

```
$tumblelog.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $tumblelog.masonry({
            columnWidth: 1,
            isOriginTop: true,
            itemSelector : '.item'
    });
});
```